# Called file with exit /b exits main file batch

Tags: batch-file

I have two files:

File1.bat:

```
@echo of
File2.bat
pause
```

File2.bat:

```
@echo off
echo hello
exit /b
```

I expect File1.bat to call File2.bat and then pause, however the `exit /b` command is exiting the console like a plain `exit` command. Why is this?

Comment: To clarify RalfFriedl's answer, invoking a batch file directly _chains_ that file, ie its contents replace the remainder of the calling file, so only `File2.bat` is active when `exit /b` is executed. Using `call File2.bat` suspends `File1.bat`, which resumes when `File2.bat` completes.

Comment: Alternatively, add a :end at the very end of your File2.bat and instead of writing exit /b, type goto end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you didn't use `call` when calling the second file, so it wouldn't return no matter what it does.

Try

```
@echo of
call File2.bat
pause
```

Comment: interesting I didnt know that was how it works. Thank you.